# Need to execute a jar file using bat file

Tags: batch-file, jar

Need to execute a runnable jar file in widows machine and dont know whether the system already installed java or not.In case if the java is not installed in the machine the bat file  has to install the java and then execute the jar file.The possibility may be like below.

1. check the whether java installed in the machine or not
2. If not installed install in the machine install the java and execute the jar file
3. If already java installed in the machine run the jar file.

Help  me to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than a batch file you could consider using a tool like [launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/) to generate an `.exe` wrapper. An executable built by launch4j will prompt the user to download java if they don't already have a suitable version installed.